# read files/folders from usb using vc++2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I wanna read/write files/folders from USB mass storage in windows7 using Visual studio 2010.

Using WM_DEVICECHANGE am able to detect connection/removal of USB device.
But now I donno how to read the files and folders from USB(Pendrive).

I dont wanna install any packages to do this. By using windows classes let me know if I can work.

Please help me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Register a window with RegisterDeviceNotification and can successfully receive DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE messages
.
In WM_DEVICECHANGE handler you have to get dbcc_name. it will be something like \?\USB#VID_05AC&PID_1294&MI_00#0#{6bdd1fc6-810f-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f}

This id identifies the USB device.

The following psuedo can be used (The code is in C# but can be easily ported to c++).

```
Private static string GetDeviceName(String DbccName)
{
    string[] Parts = DbccName.Split('#');
    if (Parts.Length >= 3)
    {
        string DevType = Parts[0].Substring(Parts[0].IndexOf(@"?\") + 2);
        string DeviceInstanceId = Parts[1];
        string DeviceUniqueID = Parts[2];
        string RegPath = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Enum\" + DevType + "\\" + DeviceInstanceId + "\\" + DeviceUniqueID;
        RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(RegPath);
        if (key != null)
        {
            object result = key.GetValue("FriendlyName");
            if (result != null)
                return result.ToString();
            result = key.GetValue("DeviceDesc");
            if (result != null)
                return result.ToString();
        }
    }
    return String.Empty;
}
```

Once you get the friendly name, you can use windows API to read/write files to USB drive.